# SDK version for Android version 4.0

Tags: android, sdk, version

I want to know what is the "android:minSdkVersion" and the "android:targetSdkVersion=" to use my android app on mobile-phone with Android version 4.0 .

Comment: min sdk =11 and target sdk= 22

Answer (score 1):

Target Should always be the latest that you have installed on your PC . ie: 22.
Minimum would be 14.

Answer (score 0):

The API 14 is the one related to Android 4.0. So you could put targetSdk to 14. The minSdkVersion is the minimal android API that will be allowed to install your app so for more users, the lower the better !
Still, if you set targetSdk to higher API, like 22, your Android 4.0 device will be able to installyour app.